# Capture key event from GtkMenuItem in C

Tags: c, gtk3

I searching a way to capture key event from GtkMenuItem with GTK 3.2+ (3.24).

With the following line, I successfully capture key event on my window (when window is focused, when a combo entry is focused, when a button is focused, when a scale is focused...).

```c
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "key-release-event", G_CALLBACK (my_function), NULL);
```

But this does not work with my menubar. Is there a way to do that? I see in GTK documentation that I can use **gtk_event_box_new**, but I don't understand the trick. Is someone can help?

Comment: Here are examples about [How GtkEventBox works](https://youtu.be/0dHTANP8MIg)

Comment: Oh yes! That's me, I'm stupid. I misused gtk_widget_set_events and g_signal_connect. Thank you :)